# Can't get the ID of a record in Firebase Firestore - Getting the last document only

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am not finding the right solution to my problem since several weeks already.
I have two collections.

One is named Inbox the other one is named Area_of_focus.

In Inbox, I have several documents. In the document, I have a field called AOF_Name and AOF_ID.

When I create a new document into Inbox, on my view, I have a dropdown button containing all the records from the collection Area_of_focus.

The user must select one of the record so it is assigned to the document created into Inbox.

If I can get the name of AOF, I am not able to get the right ID. I am getting the ID of the last document. I do not understand what I am missing.

I have tried to implement the solution proposed below, but I guess I am not doing it right.

Please, can you help? Many thanks.

[image: Inbox]

[image: AOF]

second option using a map

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

String myProjectName = '';
var selectedProject = '';
var selectedID = '';
DocumentSnapshot? snap;
DocumentSnapshot? snapShot;

List idAOF2 = [];
List NameAOF2 = [];
Map<String,String> MD = {};

//#########################################################################
String selectedProjectCapture = '';
String selectedContextCapture = '';
String selectedFocusCapture = '';

//##########################################################################

class CaptureV2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const CaptureV2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CaptureV2State createState() => _CaptureV2State();
}

class _CaptureV2State extends State<CaptureV2> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _captureFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String? selectedProjectCapture = '', selectedFocusCapture = '';

  TextEditingController? _controllerTaskName;
  TextEditingController? _controllerMyGoal;

  String? _valueTaskNameChanged = '';
  String? _valueTaskNameSaved = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Material(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              title: const Text('TEMP'),
              actions: const <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 22, 0, 0),
                  child: Text("TEST"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(children: [
              Form(
                  key: _captureFormKey,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            top: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

//Test
                      Theme(
                          data: ThemeData(
                              inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                          )),
                          child: Card(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  8.0, 0.0, 15.0, 1.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  hintText: "Task Name",
                                  hintStyle:
                                      TextStyle(color: Color(0xff29B6F6)),
                                ),
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 100,
                                maxLines: 3,
                                onChanged: (valTaskName) => setState(
                                    () => _valueTaskNameChanged = valTaskName),
                                validator: (valTaskName) {
                                  return valTaskName!.isEmpty
                                      ? "Task name cannot be empty"
                                      : null;
                                },
                                onSaved: (valTaskName) => setState(
                                    () => _valueTaskNameSaved = valTaskName),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )),

//Project
                      Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(
                            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        )),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                          child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                  .collection('Users')
                                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                  .collection('projects')
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                  const Text("Loading.....");
                                } else {
                                  List<DropdownMenuItem> projectItems = [];
                                  List<String> idProject = [];
                                  for (int i = 0;
                                      i < snapshot.data!.docs.length;
                                      i++) {
                                    DocumentSnapshot snap =
                                        snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                                    idProject.add(snap.id);
                                    projectItems.add(
                                      DropdownMenuItem(
                                        value: (snap['project_Name'] + snap.id),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context)
                                                  .size
                                                  .width *
                                              0.89,
                                          child: Text(
                                            (snap['project_Name'] +
                                                '---' +
                                                snap.id),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontSize: 16),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return Row(children: <Widget>[
                                    DropdownButton(
                                      items: projectItems,
                                      onChanged: (dynamic myProject) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          selectedProjectCapture = myProject;
                                        });
                                      },
                                      // value: selectedProjectCapture,
                                      isExpanded: false,
                                      hint: SizedBox(
                                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.89,
                                          height: 40.0,
                                          child: selectedProjectCapture == ''
                                              ? const Text(
                                                  'Project ?',
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Color(0xff29B6F6),
                                                      fontSize: 16),
                                                )
                                              : Text(
                                                  selectedProjectCapture!,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                      fontSize: 16),
                                                )
                                          //projectName
                                          ),
                                    )
                                  ]);
                                }
                                return Container(
                                  height: 0,
                                  width: 0,
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),

//#########AOF
                      Theme(
                          data: ThemeData(
                              inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                            border: InputBorder.none, //OutlineInputBorder(),
                          )),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                            child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                                    .collection('Users')
                                    .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                                    .collection('area_of_Focus')
                                    .snapshots(),
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                    const Text("Loading.....");
                                  } else {
                                    List<DropdownMenuItem> projectItems = [];

                                    for (int i = 0;
                                        i < snapshot.data!.docs.length;
                                        i++) {
                                      DocumentSnapshot snapShot = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
                                      AOF({'id':snapShot.id,'name':snapShot['name']});
AOF(MD).mapAOF.addAll({'id':snapShot.id,'name':snapShot['name']});

                                      projectItems.add(
                                        DropdownMenuItem(
                                          value: MD['name'],//(snapShot['name']),
                                          child: Text(MD['name']!,
                                                          //(snapShot['name']),
                                            style: const TextStyle(
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        DropdownButton(
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                              Icons.arrow_downward_outlined),
                                          items: projectItems,
                                          onChanged: (dynamic myFocus) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              selectedFocusCapture = myFocus;
                                              print((MD['name']));
                                              print ('id selected');
                                              print (MD['id']);


                                            //  var SnapshotID = snapShot?.id;

                                           //   var index =
                                           //       NameAOF2.indexOf(myFocus);
                                           //   print(idAOF2[index]);

                                            });
                                          },
                                          isExpanded: false,
                                          hint: SizedBox(
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.89,
                                            height: 40.0,
                                            child: selectedFocusCapture == ''
                                                ? const Text(
                                                    'Area of focus ?',
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xff29B6F6)),
                                                  )
                                                : Text(
                                                    selectedFocusCapture!,
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors
                                                            .black), //projectName
                                                  ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }
                                  return Container(
                                    height: 0,
                                    width: 0,
                                  );
                                }),
                          )),
                    ],
                  )),
              //bottomNavigationBar: MyBottomAppBar(),
            ]))));
  }
}

class AOF {
  Map <String, String> mapAOF ={'id':'','name':''};

  AOF(this.mapAOF);
}
```

Comment: please show structure of your firestore collection

Comment: value: (snapShot['name']) should be value: (snapShot['id']) in dropdown list item

Comment: I have just added the structure

Comment: @Hirak: Thank you. But it is not what I want to do. The user would not be able to know what this id means. But, with the name, he understands. I just want to get the ID, not to display it, but to store it into the document, so I can do query based on this ID later on.

Comment: Did you try it? What you put in value doesn't appear to user. What you put in text child appears to the user

Comment: Yes. I have tried. When the user select a text value displayed, then the ID is displayed in place of the text.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that you should be able to tell what is the name of an AOF by its ID. To do that, you need a map (or better, a dedicated class). A `Map` a simple list of key-value pairs. It looks like this :

```
var aofMap = {
    'aofId1': 'aofName1',
    'aofId2': 'aofName2',
}
```

Then you'll be able to do `aofMap['aofId1']` to retrieve `'aofName1'`.
So instead of only keeping the id in the AOF2 list, turn it into a `Map<String, String>` and do this :

```
DocumentSnapshot snapShot = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
AOF2[snapShot.id] = snapShot.name;
```

With a custom class (useful if you have more data than 1), you would use a `Map<String, CustomClass>` and write a static `fromMap(Map<String, dynamic>)` method in `CustomClass` to convert the incoming data into a `CustomClass` object. Better yet, you can use the integrated [withConverter](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#typing-collectionreference-and-documentreference) method to do it for you.

Comment: Many thanks. I will try to do it. I will keep you posted.

Comment: I have updated the code.  Not sure if I am doing it properly